# Как сделать кнопки навигации во вью?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

вперед-назад
функционал, как в кнопок браузера

```html
<button>на главную</button>
<button>вперед</button>
<button>назад</button>
```

Comment: Для начала можно открыть руководство по vue и, руководствуясь этим руководством, попробовать составить программку:)

Comment: @Sergey, смешно)) Речь о глобальной программе? вовсе нет